# Issue with JSON response, property of resultant object is being read as undefined but I can see it exists

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json response that's gained from an ajax request by a form. The response  is stored in a variable called `response` and looks like:

```
{
    data: {
      attributes:{
            //list of key-values
        }
        id: null,
        type: "job"
    },
    links: {
      modal: "/client/render/modals/job/success"
    },
    message: "job successfully created",
    success: "ActionSuccess"
}
```

The problem is when I try to do:

```
response.links.modal
```

or

```
response['links']['modal']
```

I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modal' of undefined`

Why does it seem to think that links doesn't exists when I can see it in the JSON response (I can see it exists in the Preview of the response (using chrome)).

EDIT:

code that makes the ajax request:

```
function submit_form (request,method,data,type,target) {
    switch(type){
        case 'modal':
            $('#' + target).openModal();
        break;
        case 'target':

        break;
        case 'page':

        break
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: request,
        type: method,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            submit_callback(response,type,target)
        }

    })
}
```

callback:

```
function submit_callback(response,type,target) {
    switch(type){
        case 'modal':
            console.log(response) //shows that links exists
            console.log(response.links) //logs out as undefined
            post_page(response.links.modal,response.message,target) 
        break;
        case 'target':
            change_target(response,target);
            setUpPageElements();
        break
        case 'page':
            ('body').html(response)
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Response after having used JSON.stringify on it:

```
"{\"message\":\"job successfully created\",\"success\":\"ActionSuccess\",\"data\":{\"attributes\":\"//list of key-values\"},\"type\":\"job\",\"id\":null},\"links\":{\"modal\":\"/client/render/modals/job/success\"}}"
```

Just an FYI, the attributes do exist but aren't necessary for this problem so I have removed them, they don't actually say `\"//list of key-values\"`.

Comment: You're probably trying to access the response before it's really available. Post the code that performs the ajax call.

Comment: What does reponse.links print?

Comment: Check code, I added comments but just incase you miss it, it prints out as `undefined`.

Comment: Can you post your ajax request? confirm that you either dont have a dataType(default is json). You may also be trying to access the response before the success callback

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` output?

Comment: I would suggest JSON.stringify response and its either going to break because its not valid json or expose the problem because there is nothing wrong with your usage of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out the problem wasn't on the front end but the back end; For some reason It wasn't returning the response as json but as text, after fiddling around with the code I fixed the problem, it now returns JSON as JSON rather than a JSON string.

Remember kids, always ensure that the server is returning as the correct type!

Comment: My comment would have been "`add dataType: 'json'`" indeed to force the response as `application/json` and not (probably) `text/plain`.